# ParseCrashReporting - Crash Reports not appearing in Dashboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, crash-reports

I have an iOS app in production that uses Parse for User authentication and some analytics and have successfully used Parse in several other apps. Recently, I added the Crash reporting functionality to the app but after two days of head banging and dozens of crashes I'm still not seeing anything appear in the Parse Crashes dashboard. Additionally I created a brand new single view app with nothing but the Parse Crash Reporting (and dependencies) added to it to no avail.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I've done thus far including the troubleshooting steps suggested by Parse as well as what I've found on StackOverflow and the Google Developer boards

Steps to enable Crash Reporting (with the correct AppId and Client Key of course):

```
// Enable Crash Reporting
[ParseCrashReporting enable];

// Setup Parse
[Parse setApplicationId:@"parseAppId" clientKey:@"parseClientKey"];
```

I then used the suggested code to "simulate" a crash by throwing an exception. Works like a charm but nothing shows up on Parse's end!

Parse Troubleshooting Suggestions:

[x]Make sure you've enabled Crash Reporting in your App Delegate before you initialize Parse.

[x]If you're testing, make sure Xcode isn't catching the crash with the debugger. Build, run, stop the app, and then run it from the home screen.

[x]Crashes are sent on the next run of the app. Make sure the app isn't crashing again before it has a chance to send the crash information. If you're testing, you can ensure this by adding a delay.

[x]Crashes may take up to a minute to show up on the dashboard. (Some users reported waiting several hours, its been well over 24 hours)

[x]Make sure you don't have any other crash reporting solutions linked to your application, as they might interfere with each other. (Disabled Google Analytics and built a fresh app to ensure no interference)

Other Suggestions I've found:

[x]Switch App from Development to Prod in Settings. (Not sure what this actually does but it hasn't made a difference as my original app was already set to Prod and switching the fresh app to Prod did nothing)

[x]Some users had issues with older versions of Parse. I am on the latest version of the Parse, Bolts, and ParseCrashReporting Frameworks.

[x]Some users have had issues uploading the symbolication files. As I understand it the Crash reporting doesn't rely on these being uploaded and in any case I haven't had any issues uploading them to parse using the automatic build script they provided.

Other things I've tried:

[x]My company Wi-Fi has a proxy setup that has caused me issues in the past so I'm familiar on how to workaround but even running the app multiple times using the device's data connection (LTE) didn't cause anything to appear.

[x]My company uses AirWatch for our MDM so I've also tested on my personal iPad to see if AirWatch was somehow interfering. No dice.

I've looked at the device logs and can see that the Crash Report is being generated when the crash occurs:

```
Apr 16 10:28:38 Phils-iPad-Air ReportCrash[358] <Notice>: Saved report to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/TestApp_2015-04-16-102838_Phils-iPad-Air.ips
```

Yet there's nothing in the logs to show that the report is being submitted to Parse when the app is reopened after the crash. I see the data wheel spinning in the status bar for a second or two when the app is reopened, which is the only way to see that it is submitting according to a few responses by Parse individuals on the Google Developer boards.

Seriously!? Not even a line to say "Hey got a crash report, shucking it up to Parse" or "There was an oops, unable to submit to Parse".

So here I am posting my first question to StackOverflow hoping someone out there may have some additional suggestions on how to get the crash reports to appear in Parse's Crashes dashboard.

Comment: I heard from someone at Parse on the Google Developer boards who suggested I put in a Bug Report, which I did and have now heard back from the Facebook Team that they are able to reproduce and are investigating it further.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a bug as confirmed by Facebook, you can view the bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/465866550245217/

It has been resolved and everything is working great!